# Neo4j LOAD CSV Error: unknown protocol: c

Tags: neo4j, cypher, load-csv

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:/C:/Users/abcd/Desktop/Neo4J/fileName.csv" AS row
WITH row
RETURN row
```

This is my code for importing this csv to my database
but it is giving me **error as**

> Neo.ClientError.Statement.ExternalResourceFailed: Invalid URL
>   'C:/Users/abcd/Desktop/Neo4J/fileName.csv': unknown protocol: c

can anyone help me solve this

Answer (score 3):

Local CSV files are accessible using `file:///` URL.

`file:///` URLs identify files on the filesystem of the database server

You need to add `file` as protocol before the local files address, as follows:

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:///C:/Users/abcd/Desktop/Neo4J/fileName.csv" AS row
WITH row
RETURN row
```

> **NOTE:**
>
> You need to change **`neo4j.conf`** file for allowing CSV import from
>   file URLs.

**Uncomment this line(remove #):**

```
#dbms.security.allow_csv_import_from_file_urls=true
```

**Comment this line(Add # in the start):**

```
dbms.directories.import=import
```

**Don't forget to restart Neo4j after these changes.**

Comment: Are you still getting `unknown protocol: c` or something else?

Comment: I am using neo4j browser and unable to find this file can you please help me with this? where can i get this file?

Comment: File locations are different for different installations. Please check this link https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/file-locations/

Comment: Do you mean Neo4j desktop Or server?

Comment: By default only files from the import directory are read. If you want to have arbitrary directory access you have to allow that in neo4j.conf

Answer (score 0):

try below line, use some extra slashes

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:///C:/Users/abcd/Desktop/Neo4J/fileName.csv" AS row
WITH row
RETURN row
```